# Convert timesync qword into time and vice versa

Tags: python, datetime, time, reverse-engineering

I am making a clientless api for a program and the client seems to use a custom timer for it's udp packets to ensure time sync with the server, I am trying to create it now but a little unsure how it is structured, I believe the format is similar to DD:HH:MM:SS:ss, It's used to help the server dictate what the latency is between client and itself, so year/month does not seem to be used. here is a sample I took just today.
[image]

By the looks of it it is formatted in milliseconds, e.g there's a 0x65(101) increment between when a packet is sent 0.101 second from the other.

```
def MS(time_str):
    d, h, m, s, ms = time_str.split(':')
    return int(d) * 86400000 + int(h) * 3600000 + int(m) * 60000 + int(s) * 1000 + int(ms)


print(MS('12:8:23:45:100'))

Results -> 1067025100
```

The code I have doesn't seem functional this far, I need to always output 9 digits, my goal is to be able to reproduce a date from this hex qword timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question incase someone ever wonders the same, Python makes it rather easy:

```
from datetime import timedelta

millis = 450109990
output = timedelta(milliseconds=millis)

output -> 5 days, 5:01:49.990000
```

It gets reset back to zero after reaching 49 days, 17:02:47.295000 (0xFFFFFFFF)